# c++ operator() behavior

Tags: c++, std

Consider, I'm use std::for_each and object with overloaded operator() to accumulate some data about vector content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct A{
    int a;
    A(): a(0){}

    void operator()(int i) {
        if(i)   a++;
        std::cout << "a:" << a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //test data
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(0);

    //accumulator
    A accum;

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), accum);
    std::cout << "non-zero elements:" << accum.a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This [outputs](http://ideone.com/LmRRK):

```
a:1
a:2
a:2
non-zero elements:0
```

Why is `non-zero elements` 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::for_each()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) does not take its third argument by reference, so a *copy* of `accum` is made.

If you add `std::cout` statements to `A::A()` you can witness this behaviour.

Just to note, you can solve this particular problem using [`std::count_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
std::cout << "non-zero elements: "
          << std::count_if(vec.begin(),
                           vec.end(),
                           [](const int i) { return i != 0; })
          << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally<sup>1</sup> the algorithms provided by the standard library don't take the functor by reference, but by value, so you can't inspect its final state "from the outside", since the functor you passed is untouched.

Fortunately, `for_each` returns a copy of the functor after it has been applied to all the elements, so, what you need to do is:

```
accum = std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), accum);
```

Notice that, since two copies are involved here, it's usually better to have "trivial" functors whose copy is cheap, and it's important to provide a copy constructor if the one generated by the compiler won't do.

Still, as others pointed out, there are better suited algorithms for the task you are performing.

---

1. Nitpicker's corner: I didn't actually check them all, although this seems to be the "normal" behavior I've seen for all the ones I used.

Comment: but won't `accum = for_each(...)` be treated as a copy too? so accum would require a copy constructor?

Comment: @Qnan: yes, it's a copy too, but, if your functor is a "trivial" class the default copy constructor will do.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library algorithms generally copy their argument functor, so chances made to its state won't be visible.

You're really trying to use the wrong algorithm here.

`for_each` is intended to apply an operation to every element in a sequence, and nothing more.

If you want to iterate over the sequence and accumulate some kind of data , you should use... `std::accumulate`. :)

The algorithm takes one additional parameter, which is the "state", and this state is returned once the algorithm finishes.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, different instances of `A` are used since `std::for_each` doesn't take the functor as reference. You can see this if you [slightly modify your code](http://ideone.com/vIGx1) to print the address of `A::a`:

```
a:1  @0xbf86902c
a:2  @0xbf86902c
a:2  @0xbf86902c
non-zero elements:0  @0xbf869050
```